# Sql Parameterising with PgSql using EF Core and C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm trying to execute an SQL query using C# and EF Core that takes a parameter. I believe the parameter is being ignored

The code I'm using is

```
string sqlQuery = @"SELECT ""Studies"".* 
                    FROM ""Studies"" 
                    INNER JOIN ""Searches"" on ""Searches"".""StudyId"" =""Studies"".""StudyId"" 
                    WHERE ""Searches"".""Document"" @@ to_tsquery('@text')";

      
IQueryable<Study> studies = _studiesContext.Studies.FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery, new NpgsqlParameter("@text", "fire"));
```

What I'm expecting to happen is that I get the same rows back from my database as if I run the following command into the Postgres console:

```
SELECT "Studies"."StudyId", 
        "Studies"."Title",
        "Studies"."Author"
FROM "Studies"
INNER JOIN "Searches" on "Searches"."StudyId" ="Studies"."StudyId" 
WHERE "Searches"."Document" @@ to_tsquery('fire');
```

But I do not. Instead, I get the same results back as if I type the following into the Postgres console:

```
SELECT "Studies"."StudyId", 
        "Studies"."Title",
        "Studies"."Author"
FROM "Studies"
INNER JOIN "Searches" on "Searches"."StudyId" ="Studies"."StudyId" 
WHERE "Searches"."Document" @@ to_tsquery('@text');
```

I believe that `@text` is not being replaced with `fire` in my query

The EF Core logs show:

```
Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[@text='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "Studies".*
FROM "Studies"
INNER JOIN "Searches" on "Searches"."StudyId" ="Studies"."StudyId"
WHERE "Searches"."Document" @@ to_tsquery('@text')
```

I feel like I'm missing something that should be obvious?

Comment: Remove single quotes: `to_tsquery(@text)`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the single quotes around @text are the problem, try without them